# goto statement between methods C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am running some code to quickly test.  I know I would almost never use a goto statement, but I need to test if certain parts of a method work at a certain period of time, and I'm just curious.  I know that I can jump between lines of code in visual by right clicking in a method and say go to cursor, or a goto statement inside of that method, but what if I want to test certain code at a certain time, In a different method? If I wanted to see if it would work in a given situation without recreating that line of code?  I read http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_goto_statement.htm about goto statements, but when trying it in between class methods, it won't recognize the statement.  I guess I could try method calls and goto's, but I'm really curious for curiosity sake for one, and two it isn't like I'm using the code.  I just need to test something quickly.

Answer (score 2):

> when trying it in between class methods, it won't recognize the statement.

That's right. You need to define a label in order to use `goto` statement. The scope of label definitions is local to functions, so jumping to a label in a different function is not allowed.

It wouldn't be of much help anyway, because in order to get into a function you need more context than just the line position in the code: among other things, you need to provide the state for all parameters, all variables, loop counters, and so on.

On top of that, there are restrictions even on using `goto` within the same function: you cannot jump over a variable definition and use that variable after that.

Comment: And that's fine.  I realize it would be very rare to need this, but I really like the visual studios debugger, and I'd set variable values dynamically with that.  Thanks!